# Google apps script Panels Layout- Set width horizontal panel

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a horizontal panel containing two vertical panels (1 left, 1 right) When I assign a width to the horizontal panel (say 80%) the left and right vertical panel are glued to their respective sides of the horizontal panel. So there is a gap between the two vertical panels. 
How can I make the two panels appear side by side and any extra space be left on the right of them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illustration :

[image]

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('panels');
  var hor = app.createHorizontalPanel().setWidth('80%').setHeight('200px').setBorderWidth(2).setStyleAttribute('background', 'yellow');
  var vp1 = app.createVerticalPanel().setBorderWidth(5).setWidth('100%').setStyleAttribute('background', 'green');
  var vp2 = app.createVerticalPanel().setBorderWidth(5).setWidth('100%').setStyleAttribute('background', 'red');
  vp1.add(app.createLabel('panel1').setHeight('150px'))
  vp2.add(app.createLabel('panel2').setHeight('150px'))
  app.add(hor);
  hor.add(vp1).add(vp2)
  return app
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the vpanels to 100%